# Lotus Notes Script

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to have a script which can copy the value from `InternetAddress` Field in the person document one by one in `names.nsf` and append it in the `User Name` field. Can someone help with a working script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to include in your question code that you have already tried to get to work in order for others to help you (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need a script? You are welcome to write it.... this site is not about „give me a solution for my problem“ but about „help me find a solution to a problem I encountered when writing it myself“... show us what you did already: did you read the manual? Do you know about agents? Do you know, that there are two languages in Notes/ Domino: LotusScript and @Formula? You might find out, that with latter your question can be solved with one line of code... but you need to research...

Answer (score 3):

This can literally be done with a one-line formula, using a simple assignment statement and the list append operator. It is really the most basic thing you can do in all of Lotus Notes programming. It doesn't even need to use any of the @functions.

The syntax for an assignment is:

```
FIELD fieldThatYouWantToSet := value;
```

The syntax for the list append operator is:

```
value1 : value2;
```

The only other thing you need to know is that value1 and value2 can simply be the names of existing items (a.k.a. fields), and the list of values in the second item will be appended to the list of values in the first item.

Then, all you will need to do is to put this one-liner into a formula agent that runs against all documents in the current view, and run the agent from the Actions menu while you are in the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option-1:
```

There are a few ways to accomplish this, the simplest being , as the user specified before, a simple field function would do.

```
FIELD UserName := UserNAme:InternetAddress;
```

You could set and run the above field function in an agent in $UsersView

In option-2, you could also use the "UnProcessedDoc" feature and set and run as an agent.
But, here, I have written one another way to set and run as an agent in $UsersView.

Hope this helps, please approve this answer if this had helped anyone.

```
Option:2
```

At present , no Domino in my System, in order to test this snippet. I wish there exists any method online to test this snippet before I post.

But, logically, consider this snippet as a pseudo-code to accomplish ur objective.
Above all, it has been more than a decade or two ever since I have programmed in Domino. Because, I moved on to RDMS, DW, BI and now to Cloud... well Cloud-9. :)

Here is a portion of lotus script code to copy the value from InternetAddress Field in the person document one by one in names.nsf and append it in the UserName field.

```
Dim db As New NotesDatabase( "Names Db", "names.nsf" )   
Dim view As NotesView
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim InternetAddress_value As Variant

Set view = db.GetView( "$Users" )

// loop thru all docs in $Users view.
// Get InternetAddress_value and rep it in UserName
Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
If doc.HasItem("InternetAddress") Then
  While Not(doc Is Nothing)
      // in this line we concatenate username with IAaddress_value
      new_value= doc.GetItemValue( "username" ) + doc.GetItemValue( "InternetAddress" ) 
      Call doc.ReplaceItemValue( "UserName", new_value)
      Call doc.Save( False, True )
      Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
  Wend
End If
```

> This solution is posted by Mangai@Notes@Domino@Now_HCL . Encourage to post more solutions by approving the answer.